# Create custom API endpoint to change custom header image

Tags: php, functions, api, custom-header, header-image

My goal is to create a custom API endpoint that I can call with an API call that changes the custom header image in Wordpress to another image (which would be passed along the API call, or maybe just switch to another media file in Wordpress, or similar).

***UPDATE:*** I have now found the set_theme_mod() function which seems to be what I'm looking for, but when I tried to implement it I couldn't quite get it to work. The API call seems to be setup correctly because when I call it, the current header image dissappears. The problem is though that the new image does not get set.

Big thanks in advance.

```
function cs_set_logo() {
    set_theme_mod('header_image', $_POST['http://sprinth.xyz/britetest/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/Universe-logo-test.png']);
    return;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('cs/v1', 'changelogo', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'cs_set_logo'
    ]);

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Sack Exchange. Are you wanting to store the image paths and other data somewhere in the database such as a custom post type then have that data available in the API endpoint? If so, you may want to start here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

As for changing the image, if you can do it on page load with inline CSS that may be easiest. If you are wanting to do something else do you mind adding clarity to your question?

Comment: Thank you for that @Brooke . I know how to create a custom endpoint as stated in the link you attached, but I don't know what to put in the function that I call via an API Post request to update the custom header image. Like f.eg. **is there a method** that takes in an image as a parameter and updates the current header image in WP? I haven't found any method like that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header image falls under what WordPress calls **theme modification values.** To update that type of value, use the function [`set_theme_mod()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_theme_mod/)

```
function cs_set_logo($request) {
 set_theme_mod('header_image', $request->get_param('new_header_image'));
 return new WP_REST_Response(null, 200);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('cs/v1', 'changelogo', [
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'cs_set_logo'
  ])
});
```

Comment: Big thanks, this is what I was looking for. I've tried to implement it, but I can't get the image to be passed in when I call the endpoint. I have now updated the main question with a code snippet with your code. Would be greately appreciated if you could take a look :)

Comment: $_POST is a key=>value array containing all of the values sent in a POST request to the server. You're trying to access the value of a key called `http://sprinth.xyz/britetest/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/Universe-logo-test.png`. If you send a request like this `'new_header_image' => 'http://sprinth.xyz/britetest/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/Universe-logo-test.png'`, then you use the key `new_header_image` to access the value. It all depends on how you send your API request.

Comment: Okey, I see. Now I tried to send a request like this, but it still won't work. What am I missing now, haha? `axios
        .post(
          "https://sprinth.xyz/britetest/wp-json/cs/v1/changelogo",
          {
            new_header_image:
              "https://sprinth.xyz/britetest/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/Universe-logo-test.png"
          },
          {
            headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ${token}' }
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        });       `

Comment: Let's continue over chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107832/changing-header